# Public IP address for each node in a LAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

Whenever I go to [IP lookup](http://whatismyipaddress.com) from any device on the same LAN it shows the same IP address, which is the gateway's public address, Is there any possible way- perhaps through the router's configuration page- to assign an IP address for each node independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no - most routers will let you do this, however it does not help you (if you are talking about regular IPV4 addresses) unless your ISP routes those IP addresses to you (ie you can't just pick whatever addresses you want or just take them from the ISP)- typically they will either refuse or will want a lot of money to do that.

You might want to ask another question stating your purpose and maybe we can provide some suggestions / workarounds for your usage case.

**Update**

You can run a webserver without any further "real world" IP addresses.  The process is thus:

1. Log into your router and find the section that defines DHCP - You will
   usually find the range of IP addresses specified and is less then all the
   available addresses in the range - for example, a router might specify
   a DHCP range of 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.200  - if this is the case
   (and if your netmask is something like 255.255.255.0 or 255.255.0.0),
   you can specify any IP address in 192.168.1.x except the addresses
   already in use and the addresses in that DHCP range - Be careful you
   don't use the gateway address though - this would normally be 
   192.168.1.1 or 192.168.1.254.
2. In your router you would then port map (or pinhole) port 80 to the
   IP address you have chosen - which will instruct the router to forward
   web traffic on port 80 from the external address to the internal address.
3. You would set your computer up with a static IP address (IE you would
   not use DHCP) - the gateway and DNS servers would be as defined in the
   router [ or available on any of the other PC's ]
4. In order to access the site internally you would access it with the
   internal IP address.  In order to access the site externally you would 
   need to know what the external address is.   You can use a Dynamic DNS
   service to convert the IP address into a DNS address which checks and
   updates periodically.  The Dynamic DNS software can run on your PC or
   maybe on your router - depending on your router.

Comment: my purpose is: I have just installed apache server on my PC and I would like to see it from other devices outside my network, and keeping in mind that I will do the IP lookup to know the address each time, I just want to see the server from an external network before I actually purchase the public static IP

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this requirement - you don't actually need a public address on your computer to do this.